# How to display array in table using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

Unlike other JSON data , I have simple arrays of two.

```
$scope.land = [ elephant, tiger, zebra ];
$scope.water = [ fish , octopus, crab];
```

I want to put up the array in table using `ng-repeat`. I tried this but data is not showing in proper format.

```
<table class="table table-dark">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">LAND</th>
            <th scope="col">WATER</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="l in land track by $index">
            <td>{{l}}</td>
            <td>fish</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT:-
err in data showing vertical in table**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37EgN.jpg)

[image]

new data :-

```
$scope.land = [ 'tiger in zoo', 'tiger in jungle', 'zebra'];
 $scope.water = [ 'fish in pond'];
```

Comment: Use JS code in your controller to zip the two arrays into a single one: [{land: elephant, water: fish}, {land: tiger, water: octopus},...], then use a simple, traditional ng-repreat displaying every object in this single array.

Comment: @JBNizet necessary to have in single one ?

Comment: No, but it's the simplest, obvious, efficient way.

Comment: @JBNizet I got it , but I cannot change the array , if in this way anyhow it is possible then my time will be save.

Comment: Why couldn't you do that? If you develop an AngularJS application, then you're supposed to write some JS code at some point, not just HTML code. The controller's role is to make it easy for the view to display stuff. So yes, you can do that, and you should. There's no valid reason why you couldn't do that.

Comment: @JBNizet you didn't get me , I can do that and right now I am doing the same . I just wanted to know if there is some procedure that can be done in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to display elements of two arrays next to each other (correct me if i'm wrong).

Here is a simple way to do that :

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.land = [ 'tiger in zoo', 'tiger in jungle', 'zebra'];
    $scope.water = [ 'fish in pond'];
    $scope.combined = [];
    var maxLength = ($scope.land.length > $scope.water.length) ? $scope.land.length : $scope.water.length;
    //length is to be determined
    for(var index = 0; index < maxLength ; index++) {
     $scope.combined.push({
       land: ($scope.land[index]) ?  $scope.land[index] : '',
        water: ($scope.water[index]) ? $scope.water[index] : ''
      });
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <table class="table table-dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">LAND</th>
        <th scope="col">WATER</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in combined">
        <td>{{item.land}}</td>
        <td>{{item.water}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly thanks . But why length of land only  is determined `scope.land.length` ?

Comment: Also my data is showing in vertical  way. Can you guess why ? I am adding pic in EDIT

Comment: The loop is iterating over the land array which can be the water also if they have the same number of elements , i placed that comment just for reference

Comment: There can be more and less on either side. Then how it will be possible ?

Comment: is that case you can take the longest array and place the number of items in the loop. i've updated the snippet for that case

Comment: i see that the items in the picture you've added contains different data, do you have a different array structure, don't forget the add quotes to animal names like this : `'tiger'`

Comment: No , I have same structure as you have mentioned. Yes it is in `"  "`. Even I am passing the same data as I have mentioned in the question , it is breaking down

Comment: that's weird, the land array contains a `'talk'` and water has `'not'` element right ?

Comment: can you add that data in the question please ?

Comment: I have added please check. I think because of space it is breaking down

Comment: it's still working, i've updated the snippet with the new data, it think there is an issue in the html, can you check the html structure maybe the loop is not in the right place .

Comment: Maybe there is an unclosed html tag

Comment: Oh, I got it . I have am getting the the details in a single string `[ "tiger in zoo, tiger in jungle, zebra"]`. I need to break it down

Comment: yes, you can do that with a [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)